# How to jQuery multiple select on change function, get number of items not selected?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-selectpicker

Is there any way to get all "Not selected" values in a multiple select on a jquery onChange event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of the `:not()` and `:selected` selectors to achieve this. To then build an array of all the unselected values you can use `map()`. Try this:

```js
$('#foo').change(function() {
  var unselectedValues = $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  
  console.log(unselectedValues);     
});
```

```css
select { 
  width: 30px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="foo" multiple="true">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I want values of options not selected.

Comment: In which case you can use `map()` with the given selector to build an array. I've updated my example for you

Comment: I was looking for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you try :

axey it's your value.

```
var tab= [];

     for(var i = 0; i < axey.options.length; i++)
     {
        if(!axey.options[i].selected == true)
        {
         tab.push(axey.options[i].value);
        }
     }

console.log(tab.length);
```